# PostgreSQL: Many-to-Many listing with count

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, join, plpgsql

I have the following tables:

- libraries
- books
- librairies_books

And the following:

- A `library` has many books through the table `libraries_books`.
- A `book` can belong to many libraries through the table
  `libraries_books`.

I need to display library stats:

```
Name, Number of copies, Number of books
```

So if a library has 3 copies of Book-1, and 4 copies of Book-2, the stats should display

```
"Library 1", 7, 2

7 is the number of total copies
2 is the number of books
```

Here is the current function but it does not return the valid books count.

```
create or replace function listing()
returns table (
  "ID" int,
  "NAME" varchar,
  "NUMBER OF COPIES" bigint,
  "NUMBER OF BOOKS" bigint) as $$
begin
  return query
    select libraries.id, libraries.name, count(libraries_books.id), count(books.id)
    from libraries
    left join libraries_books
    on libraries.id = libraries_books.library_id
    left join books
    on libraries_books.book_id = books.id
    group by books.id, libraries.id;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `count(distinct)`.  In addition, use table aliases so queries are easier to write and to read:

```
select l.id, l.name, count(distinct l.id), count(b.id)
from libraries l left join
     libraries_books lb
     on l.id = lb.library_id left join
     books b
     on lb.book_id = b.id
group by l.id, l.name;
```

You also need to fix the `group by`, so it does not include the book id.